# Homeomorphism on the Hilbert space

Tags: general-topology, hilbert-spaces

We can consider two different topologies on the Hilbert space ; $l^{2}(\mathbb{N})$. 
One is the topology deduced from the norm 
\begin{equation*}
\|f\|=\sqrt{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(n)^{2}}, 
\end{equation*}
and the other one is a subspace topology from $\mathbb{R}^{\omega}$ on $l^{2}(\mathbb{N})$.

I want to prove or disprove that the above two topological spaces are homeomorphic.

The only thing I found is the identity map is not open, so the two topologies are not equal.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I'd like to follow your question.  Can you remind me what the standard topology is on $\mathbb{R}^\omega$.  I presume that is the set of real valued functions?

Comment: @muaddib It's the product topology, i.e. the topology of pointwise convergence.

Comment: In the above case, I meant $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$ equipped with the usual product topology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is enough to show that $(l^2(\omega), \tau)$ where $\tau$ is the product topology on $\mathbb{R}^{\omega}$ restricted to $l^2(\omega)$ is not completely metrizable. Suppose not. Then $l^2(\omega)$ must be a dense $G_{\delta}$ subset of $\mathbb{R}^{\omega}$. But then $l^2(\omega)$ is comeager in $\mathbb{R}^{\omega}$ which is easily refuted by observing that the sets $A_n = \{x \in l^2(\omega) : \sum_k (x(k))^2 < n\}$ are nowhere dense in $\mathbb{R}^{\omega}$.

Comment: Can you explain why completely metrizable implies it is a dense $G_\delta$ subset?

Comment: This is a theorem of Mazurkiewicz: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%CE%B4_set

Answer (score -1):

Consider the sequence $e_k = \langle 0, 0, \dots, 1, 0, 0, \dots  \rangle$ where $1$ occurs at the $k$-th coordinate. This sequence converges to the constant sequence $\overline{0} = \langle 0, 0, 0, \dots \rangle$ in the (product) topology $\mathbb{R}^{\omega}$ simply because every basic open neighborhood of $\overline{0}$ contains $e_k$ for all sufficiently large $k$. But in the Hilbert space $l_2(\omega)$ this sequence has a constant distance $\sqrt{2}$ from $\overline{0}$. Hence the two topologies are different.

Comment: So the identity map is not a homeomorphism; the OP already proved that. How do you know there is no homeomorphism between these two spaces?